# How to find out the subject of an email (in the form of a sentence) or a pdf document in NLP using Python

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining, topic-model

How to find out the subject of an email (in the form of a sentence)  or a pdf document in NLP using Python. If I do topic modelling and get different groups of topic, how do I pick out the only topic best suited for the document and join back all the words to form a meaningful sentence as the email/document subject.